# CVS Tagged Files Report

Tags: cvs, tags, report

I found this question: How to find out which CVS tags cover which files and paths?

However, the results are not at all what I'm expecting.
I'm using the following:

```
cvs -n -q update -r ET30908
```

I'm looking for every file tagged with 'ET30908'.

Answer (score 1):

I find the easiest way to do this is to check out the project.

```
cvs co -d tag-ET30908 -r ET30908 modulename
```

This will create a directory on disk called "tag-ET30908" that contains only those files with the tag specified.

You can even keep this directory around and later do updates with `cvs update` to see what tag changes have occurred.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to know this is to iterate on all files as CVS is file-oriented, not changeset or snapshot-oriented.  There is no central file/place where all tags are entered.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, what about:

```
cvs -q rlog -SR -rET30908 .
```

Note the period character at the end. This essentially means to search the entire repository. You can of course also limit your search to a specific module instead.

Also note that the `-S` parameter is not supported by some older versions of CVS and CVSNT. Without it you would get an entry for every single file even if they don't match the given tag.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a comparison with the HEAD of the tree

```
cvs rdiff -s -r ET30908 -r HEAD modulename
```

rdiff allows you to to look without a checkout

if you want to compare with your version you could tag the space you are in and 
then do the rdiff with that tag